# Exclude character to convert into decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an insert like this

```
INSERT INTO (keyMolde, nEficiencia, nCavidades )
VALUES (Origen.keyMolde, Origen.nEficiencia, 
        CASE WHEN CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS INT) = Origen.sCavidades 
                THEN Origen.sCavidades  
                ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12, 0)) 
        END);
```

Problem is into `Origen.nEficiencia`, I'm getting values like: `290%` or `91%` and I need to convert it to `91.0` or `290.0`

How can I convert it? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) function

```
REPLACE (Origen.nEficiencia, '%', '.0')

INSERT (keyMolde, nEficiencia, nCavidades )
VALUES (Origen.keyMolde, 
        CAST(REPLACE (Origen.nEficiencia, '%', '.0') AS decimal(18,2)), 
        CASE WHEN CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS INT) = Origen.sCavidades 
             THEN Origen.sCavidades  
             ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12,0)) 
        END);
```

**Update**

> ```
> create table test(val varchar(20));
> insert into test values
> ('90%'),('91%'),('23% AUMA');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(val, 'AUMA', ''), '%', '.0') AS decimal(18,2))
> FROM   test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 90.00            |
> | 91.00            |
> | 23.00            |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f576b39f1f14208ee175677afda6c18b)*

Comment: and for some reazon one of my fields have an string value like "AUMA", there is any form to exclude all field?